# 90s Japanese cartoon, alternative universe where dinosaurs are used as beasts of burden, main characters try to go back to our world

Tags: story-identification, anime

I have been trying to identify a Japanese cartoon series that I used to watch in the 90s. It was about a group of friends who get transported into an alternative universe where dinosaurs still exist and are used by a pre-industrial society as beasts of burden.

The friends must travel to a far-away location where a portal is located that can take them back to our universe.

---

I recall that this cartoon was aired on Italian television before 1998, it was dubbed in Italian. I recall that the characters in the movie had to traverse an entire country to reach their destination, and that technology was banned in this alternative universe because the religion of this quasi-feudal society forbade it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [**Dino Adventure Jurassic Tripper**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jura_Tripper) (1995), otherwise known as **Jura Tripper** or ***Kyōryū Bōkenki Jura Torippā***.

> During an excursion with the marine club, a group of children is
>   transported to what is later revealed as the planet Noah, a strange
>   world that holds both human inhabitants on the scientific level of the
>   middle ages as well as various types of dinosaurs. They quickly make
>   friends with talking pterosaur Zans and Manua, an inhabitant of Noah,
>   who helps them out on more than one occasion.
>
> While trying to find a way back home, the children learn more about
>   the new world they're in, discovering the people and dinosaurs suffer
>   from oppression by the king as well as the church's prohibition of
>   science. They get into conflict with General Mosar who is interested
>   in their advanced technology and consequently have to flee from the
>   king's army as well as the priests who try to capture Zans, who
>   incidentally is the son of White Wing, the famous but passed leader of
>   the rebellion.

You can watch the show's episodes online on YouTube;

Comment: The Italian dub, which the OP watched, was named _"I segreti dell'isola misteriosa"_ (= "the secrets of the mysterious island"). Because who cares about _dinosaurs_ in the '90s?